# Javascript : can't initialize an object property with an array of function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, function

I'm stuck on this simple one :

```
var myfunc1 = function() {
    console.log('just a function');
};

var myfunc2 = function() {
    console.log('just another function');
};

var myobj = {
    id : 1,
    desc : 'an object',
    funz : [myfunc1, myfunc2]
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(myobj));
```

=> output

```
/usr/local/bin/node lab.js
{"id":1,"desc":"an object","funz":[null,null]}
```

I was hopping to have something like :

```
{"id":1,"desc":"an object","funz":[Function,Function]}
```

What do I miss ?

Comment: convert object to json will drop all the functions...

Comment: of course !! what a dumb ...

Answer (score 2):

Found on the Mozilla Developer Network:

"If undefined, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array)."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1):

Turns out functions are omitted in JSON.stringify

> If undefined, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array).
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

You could do:

```
var myobj = {
    id : 1,
    desc : 'an object',
    funz : [String(myfunc1), String(myfunc2)]
};
```

to get what you want.